# Creating Animated SST Plot with Python

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib-basemap, matplotlib-animation

I would like to create a plot that showcases sea-surface temperature changing over the years, very similar to the SST maps that NOAA creates. The image I've inserted is essentially what the plot should look like before it gets animated, the only thing is, I don't know how to create this type of plot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DvQZ.png).

I've been able to upload all of the required functions that I've found that would be necessary to create this type of plot. But trying to actually create the plot hasn't been easy, I haven't been able to find code that would produce something similar to what NOAA publishes or an animated version of the image I've inserted. Any sources or guidance would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)!

(for animations, export the frames and use something like `ffmpeg` to compile a gif, mp4...)